# Rolify dynamic calls not run or recognized by heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am getting an error for using a function provided by a special configuration on Heroku even though it works fine on my machine.

Specifically, I am using the Rolify method is_admin? on user, which is made possible by a configuration setting in an initializer file.

So far with Heroku I have migrated the database again, restarted the app and refreshed the page multiple times for each. How can I get Heroku to run the configuration file like my local machine does every time I reset the local server?

Error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `is_admin?' for #<User:0x0000000524c8e0>):
2012-07-22T09:00:53+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <% if current_user.is_admin? %>
```

Code:

```
# config/initializers/rolify.rb
Rolify.configure do |config|
  config.use_dynamic_shortcuts
end
```

Well, I tried one more thing and it worked, but here it is just in case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran $ `heroku run rake db:reset` and it worked again. Not sure why, but oh well.

**Edit:**

The issue is that if you call Rolify custom methods when the role does not exist yet in the database, it results in an error. To get around this, either seed your database with all of the roles you'll need, or better, do not use dynamic methods.

For example, instead of:
`@user.is_admin?` use `@user.has_role?(:admin)` and it will not break.

Comment: +1 for not using dynamic methods.  I spent a good 2 hours running this one down.  :sigh: